# Flutter AnimationController repeat() repaints the parent widget even though the controller is not used

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I activated the "Highlight repaints" and saw that the whole screen gets repainted all the time when using a widget with a AnimationController repeat().

Does anyone know if this is the intended behavior?

Here is a code example. If I use the widget in any screen, the whole screen is constantly repainted even if I just return a Container() and don't actually use the controller at all.

```
class ProgressBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProgressBar({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProgressBar> createState() => _ProgressBarState();
}

class _ProgressBarState extends State<ProgressBar>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController? _animController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animController =
        AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 4), vsync: this)
          ..repeat();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include where are you using the controller ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I've created another issue  before with the full code. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72397431/flutter-animationcontroller-in-statelesswidget-repaints-always-whole-screen

The problem is that the entire screen always gets repainted even if I don't use the created controller. In the above code example I just return an emty Container but if using the ProgressBar() in any screen, the screen gets repainted all the time.

Comment: Have you tried using the `RepaintBoundary` widget?

Comment: @AmirHosseinMohammadzadeh yes. Did not change anything. Can it be a problem when I'm using animations in a PageView?